# Tools for mapping business objects (DTO objects) from entities in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, data-binding, datamapper

is there any tool or utility(mapper assembly) to construct business objects from entities(which are obtained from DB using linq -> sql , entity framework or whatever..)

in the absence of one , can anyone suggest the best way that can be accomplished rather can copy pasting the properties(what i'm doing right now) from the entity classes.?

[vijay](http://apvijay.blogspot.com)

Comment: Besides LINQ, what else do you need?

Comment: linq -> sql gives me data objects. how to map them to customized bussiness object.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You map to business objects by projecting. This works even if your POCO business objects have a different shape than your entities.

```
var q = from dataObject in Context.DataObjects
        select new BusinessObject
        {
            Name = dataObject.Name,
            RelatedObjectName = dataObject.RelatedObject.Name, // works even if RelatedObject is null
            DirectChildren = from c in dataObject.Children
                             select new ChildBusinessObject
                             {
                                 Name = c.Name
                                 // etc.
                             }
            GrandChildren = from c in dataObject.Children
                            from gc in c.Children
                            select new ChildBusinessObject
                            {
                                Name = c.Name
                                // etc.
                            },
            // etc.
        };
```

Comment: that was great craig . can u suggest any tools.? to automate the same. its really tedious manually doing this for each entity.

Comment: I find LINQpad incredibly valuable for this, and it supports LINQ to Entities. It doesn't do it automatically, though. VS IntelliSense is generally enough for me, though; you end up typing very little of the actual query. I wouldn't want to do it entirely automatically because performance can be substantially better if you only select the related objects that you actually *need* for your business methods, rather than every property of the entity.

Answer (score 9):

[Automapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper)

Comment: AutoMapper won't load related entities in a single query. LINQ will.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly answering your questions - but for less complicated projects I use this product http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/ (.NET Object-Relational Mapper Tool from DevExpress)

Comment: What u have said is ORM tool . to get the data objects. i now need the business objects , to be constructed from data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using Automapper ,cmapper being a Meldmapping class ,

```
 cMapper.FillBusinessObject(ViewModel, BusinessObject);  // To map from ViewModel to BO

 cMapper.FillModel(BusinessObject, ViewModel);  // To map from BO to ViewModel
```

thank you for voting :)